# extract information from text file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

```
#config-version=FGT50B-4.00-FW-build656-130211:opmode=0:vdom=0:user=admin
#conf_file_ver=4902373584228557200
#buildno=0656
#global_vdom=1
config system global
    set access-banner disable
    set admin-concurrent enable
    set admin-https-pki-required disable
    set admin-lockout-duration 60
    set gui-policy-interface-pairs-view enable
    set gui-voip-profile disable
    set hostname "FGT50B3G07518374"
```

Now I want to extract following numbers from this file and store in different variables for later use lets us in Version, Build and Serial.

```
4.00, 656, and FGT50B3G07518374
```

these numbers can change. can anyone tell me how can i extract this information. i know i can use sed but unable to figure out its proper syntax for this requirement.

Comment: is the 656 always going to be the same as `buildno`?

Comment: no. all numbers can change. in another config file build number is build0179

Comment: i meant, are you looking for the 656 in the first line or the 656 in the third line?

Comment: it can be any... both are same. no preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk can do this in single command:

```
arr=( $(awk -F '[ =-]+' '$1=="#config"{print $4} $1=="#buildno"{print $2+0}
        $3=="hostname"{gsub(/"/, ""); print $4}' file) )

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
4.00
656
FGT50B3G07518374
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o "[0-9]\.[0-9]\+"
```

will get all numbers with decimal points (which should get you your `4.00` if your format stays the same)

```
grep -o "build[0-9]\+" | sed "s/[^0-9]\+//"
```

should get you whatever number comes after `build` in the first line

```
grep -o "\".\+\"" | sed 's/"//g'
```

should get you any single-line strings that are surrounded in quotes, which seems to give you your hostname.  Unless there might be quotes in other formats of the file.

Comment: sorry Justin dont know why but your code is not working. I am using command + filename (example: grep -o "\".\+\"" | sed 's/"//g' config_file) and it gives me strange output...bring whole data of file on output.

Comment: you have to give either the filename to `grep` (`grep ... config_file | sed ...`) or pipe it in (`cat config_file | grep ...`)

Comment: build syntax is working fine but other two are not. hostname gives alot of data (almost complete file), first one gives many other numbers as well.

Comment: @user115079 can you supply the file you are using? it seems to work fine on my system.